Accessing db from Docker container
I am having trouble setting up Docker Swarm with .NET where my goal is to create two containers one for my main C# code to run in and another for a MySQL database. The issue I am having is getting my main container to communicate with the MySQL database. I am using docker secrets to keep my passwords and the main issue I am having is that I can't even seem to access the database with the password. Firstly, here is my Startup class.
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://myurl.com", "http://client.myurl.com") 
                    .AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
            {
                x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // This is in size in bytes  (100L * 1024 * 1024; // 100 MB)
            });

            services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("/app/data"));  // Used to store cookie data and such

            services.AddSingleton<IVersionInfoService, VersionInfoService>(); // This is my custom service that allows all Controllers to access the global VersionInfo

            var dbPassword = File.ReadAllText("/run/secrets/db_user_password");
            Console.WriteLine($"Database password : {dbPassword}");
            var connectionString = $"Server=db; Port=3306; Database=mydatabase; Uid=myuser; Pwd={dbPassword};";

            services.AddDbContext<EmulatorDbContext>(options =>options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)));

            services.AddControllers();  
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) //, EmulatorDbContext context
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin"); // I added 

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {   // Specific route for updater subdomain
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            //SeedDatabase(context);
        }

Now when I start the containers using Docker Compose it runs without errors when I dont have EmulatorDbContext context listed as a parameter for the Configure method. I was using this to call 'SeedDatabase' which attempted to add something to the database. Anyways here is my EmulatorDbContext class and my docker-compose file (also keep in mind I am using port 80 to test locally ill use HTTPS after things are working).
public class EmulatorDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public EmulatorDbContext(DbContextOptions<EmulatorDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");

            // Configure serialization for the PasswordHash and PasswordSalt
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .Property(e => e.PasswordHash)
                .HasConversion(
                    v => Convert.ToBase64String(v),
                    v => Convert.FromBase64String(v))
                .Metadata.SetValueComparer(new ValueComparer<byte[]>(
                    (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                    c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v)),
                    c => c.ToArray()));

            // Configure serialization and comparison for the PasswordSalt
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .Property(e => e.PasswordSalt)
                .HasConversion(
                    v => Convert.ToBase64String(v),
                    v => Convert.FromBase64String(v))
                .Metadata.SetValueComparer(new ValueComparer<byte[]>(
                    (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                    c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v)),
                    c => c.ToArray()));
        }
    }

version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: examplerserver
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "80:80" # Listen on port 80 for HTTP, change to "443:443" for HTTPS with SSL setup
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_NAME: mydatabase
      DB_USER: myuser
      DB_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_user_password # Path to the encrypted Docker Secrets file
      JWT_KEY_FILE: /run/secrets/jwt_key
    volumes:
      - app-data:/app/data # Additional volume for storing files
    secrets:
      - db_user_password
      - jwt_key
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_root_password
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_user_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: myuser
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    secrets:
      - db_root_password # Name of the Secrets file that is encrypted and stores database password details
      - db_user_password

secrets:
  db_root_password:
    external: true # true means we need to manually create the secret outside of compose
  db_user_password:
    external: true
  jwt_key:
    external: true

volumes:
  db-data:
  app-data:


Now just for a bit more context I am running this from my Windows 10 pc where each container is running linux. I am also using the following NuGet's inside my C# application AspNetCore.HealthChecks.MySql, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBear, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets, Newtonsoft.Json, and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql. Now here is my startup script where for now I am fully removing both containers off my system and clearing their volumes before regenerating them. Keep in mind here I am using very dumb password just for testing since I wanted to ensure I was not just making typos. This cmd is ran from my VS's directory and all runs without issues.
@echo off
REM Stop and remove all Docker services and stacks
docker stack rm exampleserver

REM Waiting for Docker services to shut down completely
timeout /t 10

REM Remove Docker secrets
docker secret rm db_root_password
docker secret rm db_user_password
docker secret rm jwt_key

REM Remove Docker volumes
docker volume rm exampleserver_db-data
docker volume rm exampleserver_app-data

REM Clean up Docker networks
docker network prune -f

REM Recreate Docker secrets
echo p | docker secret create db_root_password -
echo p | docker secret create db_user_password -
echo key | docker secret create jwt_key -

REM Deploy Docker stack
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml exampleserver

REM Display Docker status
docker ps
docker service ls
docker volume ls
docker network ls

REM Follow logs of the main app service
docker service logs exampleserver_app -f
pause

I also dont get any errors when I view the logs of MySQL server besides from the main issue of it saying I cant log in with the password despite me entering in p which should be the correct password since its what I set the secret key to and is what is getting printed to my main applications console. Anyways firstly, here is me trying to access the database from console then the logs for the database.
C:\Users\me\source\repos\ExampleServer\ExampleServer>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                 NAMES                   
e000aee9a454   exampleserver:latest   "dotnet ExampleServe…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes                         exampleserver_app.1.tlpyg7nzk0xqu0tv9lzfed2i9
c9f35dc49816   mysql:5.7                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cbpkh8qhgob91h9

C:\Users\me\source\repos\ExampleServer\ExampleServer>docker exec -it exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cbpkh8qhgob91h9 mysql -h db -u myuser -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'10.0.5.4' (using password: YES)
C:\Users\me\source\repos\ExampleServer\ExampleServer>docker exec -it exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cbpkh8qhgob91h9 mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\Users\me\source\repos\ExampleServer\exampleserver>docker service logs exampleserver_db -f
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.44-1.el7 started.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.44-1.el7 started.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:13+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:13.570505Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:13.766233Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:13.822077Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:13.928807Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 70bfde36-feb3-11ee-a128-02420a000506.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:13.933986Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:14.260798Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:14.260834Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:14.261293Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:14.279962Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.771389Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.772439Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.44) starting as process 127 ...
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.775435Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.775481Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.775486Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.775488Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.775491Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.775493Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.775685Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.775782Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.776953Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.785907Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.787648Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.798820Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.807632Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.807716Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.822309Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.822892Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.822921Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.823687Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.44 started; log sequence number 2768291
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.823821Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.824021Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.824935Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240420  1:15:18
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.828053Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.828086Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.828091Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.828093Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.828589Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.828646Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.833870Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.840381Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:18.840680Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | Version: '5.7.44'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:19.648055Z 3 [Note] InnoDB: Stopping purge
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:19.668197Z 3 [Note] InnoDB: Resuming purge
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:19.672651Z 3 [Note] InnoDB: Stopping purge
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:19.680721Z 3 [Note] InnoDB: Resuming purge
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:19.684882Z 3 [Note] InnoDB: Stopping purge
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:19.693448Z 3 [Note] InnoDB: Resuming purge
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:19.697556Z 3 [Note] InnoDB: Stopping purge
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:19.705882Z 3 [Note] InnoDB: Resuming purge
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database mydatabase
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user myuser
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user myuser access to schema mydatabase
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    |
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:22.320252Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:22.320310Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:22.320317Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:22.320323Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:22.320398Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:22.321599Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:22.321856Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:22.422168Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:22.422583Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 240420  1:15:22
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:23.841240Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12219419
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:23.842508Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:23.842545Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:23.842550Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:23.842554Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:23.842555Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:23.842656Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:23.843257Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    |
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    |
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20 01:15:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    |
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.487693Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.488779Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.44) starting as process 1 ...
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.491786Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.491832Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.491837Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.491839Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.491842Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.491844Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.492037Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.492139Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.493297Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.501909Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.503666Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.515312Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.534563Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.534641Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.548618Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.549786Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.549819Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.550966Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.44 started; log sequence number 12219419
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.551105Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.551327Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.553430Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240420  1:15:24
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.555742Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.555771Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.555776Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.555778Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.556239Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.556301Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.556524Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.556581Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.556592Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.556606Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.560817Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.567423Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:15:24.567712Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | Version: '5.7.44'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:18:28.990655Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'10.0.5.4' (using password: YES)
exampleserver_db.1.rbyj8fono3cb@docker-desktop    | 2024-04-20T01:28:01.106363Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


Is the root account allowed to access mysql from an extwrnal host (e.g. the container your app runs on)?

@Shadow Yea I think its an issue with docker secrets since when I hard code the passwords into my docker-compose file it all works perfectly but it wont use the password stored within the secrets file for some reason despite being able to print the password from the secrets file from CMD. Maybe its a permission issue or something? I dont get any error notifications though but whatever password is being used to initialize the database it for sure did not come from within my secrets file.
